# Stop Chrome from asking me which account I want to log in as?

Tags: google-account, google-chrome, google-multi-login

A while back I logged into an application using another account from my company.  Now whenever I go back to that application, I am routed to the URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?{giant query string}
```

and it presents me with this window:

[image]

Is there a way I can remove the "Rift Valley" account from chrome's history so that it never has to ask me this again? I've seen suggestions that it can be removed from various sections of `chrome://settings/` including:

- People
- Advanced -> Passwords and Forms
- Probably a few others....

But none of them seem to contain this account that keeps getting suggested.  How can I remove this so Chrome stops asking me if I want to log in as them?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Chrome. This is the Google Multi-login page.

Comment: After fixing the current login (see an answer below; it'd probably also work to delete Google cookies), if you ever want to log in to that other account again, do it in an incognito window (for one time use) or a separate Chrome user profile (which you can reopen again another day, still logged in).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are signed out of **all** Google Accounts, this "choose account" page should show a button for "Remove" at the bottom (next to the "Add account" button).

[image]

Click on "Remove", and each account will show an "X" next to it.  Just click the "X" next to the account you wish to remove, and then click "Done" at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Is there not a "Delete" button there? Click delete, the X next to Rift Valley, and click done. Then login to the other account you want to use.